# deployment of WAR on IBM Websphere

Tags: java, rest, websphere

I have developed a Rest webservice using JERSEY. WIth connects with the oracle database. I have JDBC connection code in my code itself, like the url, IP and username and password. Is is really required to again to configure the database connection on the server? like giving a JNDI name etc. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the server is hosted in the live environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it really required to *again* configure

No. It is not *required* to configure the database on the server, giving it a JNDI name and so forth.

Having said that, JavaEE best practices call for design whereby an application doesn't know the specifics of how to connect to external resources (such as databases). Instead, the application should "look up" that external resource by a logical name, and receives an object through which data can be accessed.

The main benefit in that is that your application code can focus on application functionality, while the application serving environment can take care of low-level aspects such as connection pooling, statement caching and so forth.

The other benefit of following this paradigm is that your application becomes immune to changes in the location of the database: no need to recompile your code, or re-package your application, in order to refer to a different data source. Instead, you could change the data source definition in the application serving environment so it points to a different location, and you're good to go.